# Where to point Git for a new Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

What is the recommendation of where to put project files and point git. I created Java project and pointed git to the Eclipse workspace folder. Now with every save, I have a list of Eclipse files that are unstaged (if some setting are changed, git wants me to decide about that stages and also, I do not need this files in master branch).

I can apply git ignore or can move my Java files to separate folder (out of workspace) and point git to it. What's the recommendation or how it is usually done for new Java maven project and new repo?

Comment: Yes, your root folder (i.e. *above* src/main/java) should be the root of your Git repo.  Then just add .eclipse/whatever files to .gitignore.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth write that as an answer!